# Brave Browser: Disable Restore Pages on crash

Tags: chromium, brave

When Brave crashes and then asks me to restore pages

[image: Restore Pages Notification]

I **never** want this to happen.

I've dug through all settings including the flags and I can not find a way to disable this.

I even have it configured to "Open New Tab Page" on Startup.

Is there a way to disable this or do I need to bug the developers to include this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have bugged the developers before to include this feature.

For example, see the Support post
[Disable session restore after crash](https://community.brave.com/t/disable-session-restore-after-crash/102694),
which ran until March 2020, but
didn't get any positive answer from the developers.

You may of course try your hand in bugging them again, and I wish you
good luck in your endeavour.

Comment: If it isn't a feature of Chromium, it probably won't come to Brave, since based on  Chromium.  I would not expect such a core feature to come to Brave and not Chromium since it involves the restoration of sessions.

Comment: I gave up and switched to Firefox